# How To Do A Windows 10 Upgrade Install From USB?

Tags: windows-10

I am having trouble getting to the login screen in Windows. Both normal boot and Safe mode boot past the Windows logo but then end up with a black screen with a cursor and no way to login.

Ctrl-Alt-Del, Ctrl-Esc, Win-R, Win-E, Ctrl-Shift-Win-B have no effect and I am stuck with the black screen and the cursor.

I have already tried various automatic recovery options and I can't get into Windows.

- Reset this PC
- Uninstall updates (quality and feature)
- Startup Repair

Also fixes such as launching WinRE from a USB and running commands like:

```
dism.exe /Image:F:\ /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
sfc /scannow /offbootdir=F:\ /offwindir=F:\Windows /offbootdir=F:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\sfc-1.txt
```

**Therefore**, I decided to do an upgrade install and keep my personal files.

I put the ISO on a USB stick on another PC then booted from it.

However, it said that upgrade installs can only be done by launching the setup.exe from within Windows.

- Why does the installer need to be running from Windows?
- Is there any way to bypass this check? (e.g. passing the drive as a parameter or something)

Comment: Can you start in Safe Mode?  F8 Repeatedly on Restart. See if you can log in in Safe Mode. Then see if you can run Setup from the USB you have. You would need to start Safe Mode with Networking (and that means Ethernet)

Comment: If you boot from the USB stick, Windows Environment will be loaded. Run setup from there. The USB has to be bootable. Also, it may be helpful to know your PC specs.

Comment: @John I updated the question to say that I also can't get in to safe mode.

Comment: @vssher the point of this question is that you can't run the upgrade install from the  Windows Recovery Environment. How exactly are PC specs going to help in this case?

Comment: If you cannot start at all (including Safe Mode), make sure you have a backup of your email and documents and then reinstall Windows

Comment: I don't have my product key which is why I want to do an upgrade install instead of a clean install.

Comment: You do not need your product key. Windows was installed and was running at some point. The license is in the Microsoft Licensing Server. So you can reinstall and activate the same as putting in a new blank disk. I have done this and it works fine

Comment: @opticyclic Please list exactly what commands you tried _(within the question, **not** as a comment)_ and please post a screenshot of exactly what you mean by _"...having trouble getting to the login screen..."_ - I'm assuming it's launching WinRE at boot?

Comment: It is not currently possible to perform an in-place upgrade from the WinPE.  If you boot to the WinPE then you will install Windows over Windows.  Newer versions of WinPE will allow you to download Windows from this environment.  You can also Reset your installation, allowing you to keep your personal files, but will require you to reinstall your traditional Windows desktop (Win32) applications

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot login normally, or in Safe Mode, or in any way, then now you must back up your system and re-install Windows.

Since Windows is installed and was at one point running, you do not need a product key. The license and subsequent activation is held by the Microsoft Licensing Server. This works the same way as replacing a broken drive with new drive. Windows 10 allows you to install from an installation USB ISO.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer - a workaround since I think you have ran out of solutions

Get a live USB of Ubuntu

Copy all files(even the hidden ones) and folders to external hard drive

Reinstall Windows

Get your necessary files my manual search the external hard drive

**One thing for sure - it is a way to get files and folders but nothing apart from that like settings and softwares but you can try experimentally**

Comment: Since in the question only mentioned thing is to keep personal files so reset option can be chosen

Comment: I should have been explicit in the question but all the automatic repairs fail including the reset this pc option.

Comment: @user52599 If Windows is reinstalled to the same partition a previous Windows install is installed to, the installer will move all data from the root of the partition to `C:\Windows.old` prior to copying over data from the `install.esd`.  There is no reason to use Linux to backup Windows files, as Windows natively offers a multitude of solutions to do so from both WinPE/WinRE, as well as if booted to Windows (`RoboCopy`, `DISM`'s `/Capture-Image`, etc. where `DISM /Capture-Image` is superior to anything Linux or 3rd parties offer).

Answer (score 0):

Re-installing Windows should not be needed; instead, perform the correct recovery procedures in WinRE by using the `install.esd` from the Install USB (`\sources\install.esd`) to repair Windows

1. **In WinRE, *and with the install USB plugged in*, issue the following:**

   1. **Get drive letters:** `DiskPart` > `lis vol` > `exit`

      - *Note the drive letters of the Install USB and Windows OS partition*
   2. **Cleanup Component Store:**

      ```powershell
      # Where C: is the Windows OS partition:
        DISM /Image:"C:" /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup
      ```
   3. **Repair Component Store with `install.esd`**

      1. **Query the `install.esd` for the image of the Windows version installed:**

         ```powershell
         # Where Z: is the Install USB
           DISM /Get-WIMinfo /WIMfile:"Z:\sources\install.esd`
         ```
      2. **Repair Component Store *(`%WinDir%\WinSxS`)* with image Index from #1.3.1:**

         ```powershell
         # Where C: is  Windows OS partition and Z: is the Install USB
           DISM /Image:"C:" /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:wim:"Z:\sources\install.esd":6
           # Where 6 is the image index from 1.3.1
         ```

         - *`/Source` parameter can also point to an extracted `Windows\WinSxS` directory from an install/backup image or another PC with the same version of Windows*
   4. **Repair `%WinDir%`:**

      ```powershell
      # Where C: is  Windows OS partition
        SFC /ScanNow /OffBootDir="C:\" /OffWinDir="C:\Windows"
      ```
2. **If User Profile corruption is the issue *(two possible solutions)*:**

   1. **Try the following in WinRE:**

      1. **Load the OS partition's `software` registry hive:** 
          `RegEdit` > Highlight `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` > *File* > *Load Hive...* > `C:\Windows\System32\config\software` > Enter `1` as location to mount it within

         - *The `software` hive should now be mounted at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\1`*
      2. **Navigate to: `HKLM\1\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`**

         - *Identify the corrupted user's profile by selecting each `S-1-5-21-` key until you see the user reflected within the String's  `ProfileImagePath` value Data.*
      3. **Edit `DWORD`: `State`:** Change value from `1` to `0`

         - **If it doesn't exist:** 
            Right-click on the user's `S-1-5-21-` key > *New* > `DWORD` > *Value:* `State`
      4. **Unload OS' `software` hive:** 
          Highlight `1` under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` > *File* > *Unload Hive...*
      5. **Boot to Windows:** 
          Try logging in as the user > If unable, proceed to **#2.2**
   2. **Boot back to WinRE:**

      1. **Enable Administrator account**

         ```powershell
         Net User Administrator /Active:yes
         ```
      2. **Boot to Windows, logging in as *Administrator***
      3. **Backup corrupted user's `%UserProfile%`** *(`C:\Users\<UserName>`)* **to a new location**

         - *Ensure all hidden files/directories are backed up*
      4. **Create a new *Local* user:** 
          *Settings* >  *Accounts* > *Family & other users* - *Other Users* > *Add someone else...*

         - *Change new user's account type to Administrator if it was before*
      5. **Copy all *non-hidden* content to new user's `%UserProfile%` directory:**

         - *Do not copy any of the `Ntuser.*` files over to the new user's `%UserProfile%`*

           - *These files are only backed up in case you need to mount the corrupted user's `HKCU` registry hive to pull data from*
      6. **Log out of the *Administrator* account and login as New User**
      7. **Once OOBE finishes and are at the Desktop:** 
          *Settings* > *Accounts* > *Your info* - *Sign in with a Microsoft account instead*

         - This will re-sync majority of your user personalization settings from the old, corrupted account *(you may need to manually disconnect it from your Microsoft account first)*
      8. **Disable built-in Administrator account:**

         ```powershell
         Net User Administrator /Active:no
         ```

Comment: I just finished running your commands as they were slightly different to what I ran originally. Querying the install.esd was useful to check I had the right iso. `dsim` succeeded but `sfc` failed. See this other question for the problem with it https://superuser.com/questions/1514593/why-does-sfc-always-get-stuck-on-this-one-file

Comment: @opticyclic - DISM should be used over SFC when you are running Windows 8+

Comment: If DISM runs successfully, and the problem still exists, then the problem is unfortunately, beyond SFC and DISM to fix

Comment: @Ramhound Both `DISM` and `SFC` should be used, as each does different things the other relies upon.  `DISM` must be run before `SFC`, as `DISM`'s `/restorehealth` checks the Component Store (`%WinDir%\WinSxS`) for corruption against known good backup copies from the Windows Update servers, an `install.esd`/`install.wim`, or another system's `%WinDir%\WinSxS`.  `SFC` then uses the known good backups of all system files contained within `%WinDir%\WinSxS` to check for corruption of system files contained within `%WinDir%` _(this is why `DISM`'s `/restorehealth` should be run first)_